# Chrome repeatedly freezes until restart

Tags: google-chrome, macbook, buffer

On my MacBook air which I bought new in December 2019, I've recently been running into Chrome loading issues.

Chrome generally runs fine for around 15-20 minutes after a reboot, after which nothing loads and Chrome gets stuck on "Resolving Host"

I've noticed that if I'm watching a video and Chrome begins to freeze, I'll get an error message like "HLS.js error: network error fatal = True levelloadtimeout"

Is this a hardware or software problem. If it is the latter, what should I do about it? If it is the former, do I need to replace the computer to fix the issue?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Chrome? How much RAM does your MacBook have? Chrome always slows down and causes memory issues so your best bet is using a different browser, preferably Safari.

Comment: @Todd I'll try reinstalling Chrome. I think it has 16 GB of RAM? Not sure.

Comment: You can check by clicking on  > About This Mac. 16GB RAM and even 8GB is plenty to run Chrome. As I said, try reinstalling or use Safari.

Comment: Re-installing an App is utterly pointless; it will gain nothing whatsoever. Check what Activity Monitor shows hogging the CPU at the times you see the halts.

Comment: @Tetsujin When (if) it happens again, I'll check the activity monitor and update this post. I just reinstalled chrome, for whatever that's worth.

Comment: It's worth… absolutely nothing, I'm afraid. Keep AM open & visible - if you have to open it or switch to it **after** a halt you won't get the right information.

Comment: @Tetsujin So it hasn't frozen yet but it is a bit slower, and AM says the CPU percentage when it was slowing down was 40 %, but it rapidly dropped back down to 15%